# Is ::operator new not allowed in a lambda expression, or a compiler bug? (Updated!)

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, compiler-errors

My compiler is the latest VC++ 2013 preview. (**Updated!**)

```
#include <new>

struct A
{
    A(int)
    {}
};

void f(void (*fn)(void*))
{
    A a(0);
    fn(&a);
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    auto fn = [&](void* p)
    {
        //
        // error C2664: 'void f(void (__cdecl *)(void *))' : 
        // cannot convert parameter 1 from 
        // 'main::<lambda_b20f735b061d78dbb0f2f653ecbb482f>' 
        // to 'void (__cdecl *)(void *)'
        //
        new (p) A(n);
    };

    f(fn);
}
```

Why is this usage not allowed?

Is this behavior defined by the standard? If yes, what's the rationale?

Comment: Did you `#include <new>`? Placement new is not magically predefined by the compiler, it's actually a regular function defined in a standard header.

Comment: @Igor, I updated the post, please review.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Make that an answer so we can finally get over with it. `;)`

Comment: @Mark, the question has been updated. Please review the post.

Comment: Capturing lambdas are different.

Comment: It doesn't look like the `new` has anything to do with it, the error is coming from trying to pass the lambda to `f()`.

Comment: Use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of a function pointer.

Comment: @Mohammad, why is this usage not allowed? Is this behavior defined by the standard? If yes, what's the rationale?

Comment: @xmllmx, Yes, it's perfectly defined in the standard, and the rationale is common sense. Function pointers can't store state, so what do you propose as a clean way to transfer the captured variables?

Comment: @xmllmx A capturing lambda is pretty much the equivalent of a struct with members and operator() that may or may not take args.

Comment: If you remove the & from variable capture, maybe it will work. Because it will no longer need to store state.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Without the capture of `n`, the lambda won't compile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void f(void (*fn)(void*))
```

takes a function pointer, not a lambda.

```
auto fn = [&](void* p)
```

is a lambda, and cannot be reduced to a function pointer because it involves a capture.

```
void f(std::function<void(void*)> fn)
```

will work. http://ideone.com/E7vvyW

```
#include <functional>

struct A
{
    A(int)
    {}
};

void f(std::function<void(void*)> fn)
{
    A a(0);
    fn(&a);
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    auto fn = [&](void* p)
    {
        //
        // error C2664: 'void f(void (__cdecl *)(void *))' : 
        // cannot convert parameter 1 from 
        // 'main::<lambda_b20f735b061d78dbb0f2f653ecbb482f>' 
        // to 'void (__cdecl *)(void *)'
        //
        new (p) A(n);
    };

    f(fn);
}
```